# Reversing a string using only iostream, fstream, string and vector

Tags: c++11

I just started working with C++ about a week ago so I don't know much about the language. I am working on creating a program that inputs a text file and then reverses all of the lines.

So an input of:

```
"abc"

"123"
```

Would be:

```
"cba"

"321"
```

I can figure out how to input the lines from the file, but I am having trouble with my reverse function. I have tried to just print out each individual character as a string using substring, starting from length - 1 and ending at 0. But this does not seem to be working. When I run the program, I get these errors that I don't understand.. Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

[image: Heres the image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>



using namespace std;

void reverse(string input) {


for((int x=input.length()-1); x=0; x--)
cout << input.substr(x);

}
cout << endl;
}


int main()
{
string line;
ifstream myFile;
myFile.open("reverse_input.txt");

while(getline(myFile, line)) {
    reverse(line);
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple syntax errors in your code that the compiler was complaining

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>



using namespace std;

void reverse(string input) {
   for( unsigned int x= (input.length()-1); x>=0; x--) { //Missing {, extra (), >= insteadof = 0
      cout << input[x] << flush;
   }
   cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream myFile;
    myFile.open("reverse_input.txt");

    while(getline(myFile, line)) {
        reverse(line);
    }

    return 0;
}
```